# My Python Discord Bot Sends Messages To All Channels

Tags: python, discord, bots

I created a discord bot which can control a "word game". In this game, bot reads every message and then it adds their last letter into "harfkontrol" list. Then he checks every messages first letter and checks if their message starts with the last letter of previous word. It works. But problem is, it works on every channel. It must work in only one channel. What should I do? (I know `get_channel()` method, but I want it understand which channel it must read & delete messages, without my help.)

Code:

```
import discord
import os

TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']
client = discord.Client()

kullanilan_sozcukler=[]
harfkontrol = ["a"]
komutlar=["bilgi!koyunu", "liste!koyunu", "sayı!koyunu", "komutlar!koyunu"]
komutmetin = "Komutlar:\n**bilgi!koyunu:** Botun ne yaptığı ve kim tarafından yapıldığı hakkında bilgi almak için.\n**liste!koyunu:** Bot kanala eklendikten sonra yazılan kelimelerin listesi.\n**sayı!koyunu:** Yukarıdaki komutun gösterdiği listedeki kelime sayısı."

def son_harf(kelime):
  list(kelime)
  return kelime[-1]
  
def ilk_harf(kelime):
  list(kelime)
  return kelime[0]

def kontrol(kelime):
  list(kelime)
  if harfkontrol[-1] == kelime[0]:
    return True
  else:
    return False

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("{0.user}".format(client), "çalıştırıldı.")
  
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  msg = message.content
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if msg.startswith("bilgi!koyunu"):
    await message.channel.send('**Kelime Oyunu,** "Kelime Oyunu" kanalınızı yöneten bir bottur. Bot, eklendiği andan itibaren kelime oyununun kurallarına uygun oynanmasını sağlar.\n\nYapıcı:AjanSmith#4747')
    
  if msg.startswith("liste!koyunu"):
    sozcuk_listesi = ", ".join(kullanilan_sozcukler)
    await message.channel.send(f"Kullanılan sözcükler: {sozcuk_listesi}")
    
  if msg.startswith("sayı!koyunu"):
    uzunluk = len(kullanilan_sozcukler)
    await message.channel.send(f"Şimdiye kadar {uzunluk} farklı kelime kullanıldı.")

  if msg.startswith("komutlar!koyunu"):
    await message.channel.send(komutmetin)

  if msg in komutlar:
    return
  else:
    if len(list(msg)) == 1:
      await message.delete()
      await message.channel.send("Lütfen bir kelime giriniz.")
    
    elif msg in kullanilan_sozcukler:
      await message.delete()
      await message.channel.send(f"{msg} sözcüğü daha önce kullanıldı. Lütfen başka bir sözcük giriniz.")
    
    elif ilk_harf(msg) != harfkontrol[-1]:
      await message.delete()
      await message.channel.send(f"Lütfen '{harfkontrol[-1]}' ile başlayan bir kelime giriniz.")

    else:
      harfkontrol.append(son_harf((msg)))
      kullanilan_sozcukler.append(msg)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `on_message` you can get the ID of the channel the message was posted in using `message.channel.id`. You can then compare this to the ID of the desired channel to post messages in, returning from `on_message` if these do not match.

Therefore, in order to solve your issue, you could simply change

```
if message.author == client.user:
    return
```

to

```
if message.author == client.user or message.channel.id == CHANNEL_ID_HERE:
    return
```

Replacing `CHANNEL_ID_HERE` with the ID of your channel (as an integer). You can find this ID by activating Developer Mode in the advanced tab of Discord settings, then right-clicking on the channel and selecting "Copy ID".

Comment: I made it `message.channel.id != CHANNEL_ID` and it works now. Thank you too much!